# Generate a Notebook automatically

Tags: notebooks

Good evening,

I am interested in creating a Notebook with specific instructions in an automatic fashion using, say, Python.
For example, I would like to generate the file NewNote.nb (a genuine Mathematica Notebook, and not merely a .nb file) with the instruction

Print[2+2]

so that, after running my Python program, I could open NewNote.nb as I open a regular Notebook, and run it as a regular Notebook, thus getting the output 4, as expected. I do not want to run the Notebook in an automated way: all I want is to create it in such automated way.

The problem I am facing, however, is that a Mathematica Notebook has lots of internal cache informations; and if I generate a .nb file without them, it will not work as a genuine Mathematica Notebook.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not true because this notebook will work: `Export[ "test.nb", "Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[\"Print[2+2]\"], \"Input\"]}]", "Text" ]` even though no cache was added. Now, how to do this in Python is off topic here.

Comment: *"a Mathematica Notebook has lots of internal cache informations; and if I generate a .nb file without them, it will not work as a genuine Mathematica Notebook."*  This is absolutely not true. When notebooks are generated this way (as expressions), a cache is never created.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. But the reason I specifically used the word 'genuine Notebook' was to make clear that the kinds of Notebooks you are talking about are *not* the kind of Notebooks I am interested in. You are right: the Notebooks you are talinkg about (the ones without cache) work. That is, you can run them, and obtain the desired output. However, if after running them, you now decide to save them, and then open them a second time, they will look awful. And this precisely because they are not recognized by Mathematica as genuine Notebooks, but as mere .nb files.

Comment: @Duarte What you say is simply not true. The cache is not needed.  If your notebook does not work, that has nothing to do with the cache not being present.  If you don't understand why your notebook does not work, then post a *minimal* broken example notebook and we will let you know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Again I disagree! You are right: the cache is not needed for you to run the notebook. True. But now try and save this notebook, *after* you runned it. It will look a mess!, with things like "Out[1]=..." and "During evaluation of In[1]:= " etc.

Comment: Arguing is pointless. You need to show a *concrete* example: "1. I did this (exact steps!) 2. I expected this result 3. I got this result instead. How do I get result 2?"

Comment: @Duarte this mess is what notebook is about, if you want this gone, don't save it...